# How to impersonate any user in a laravel 4 app

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, impersonation, cartalyst-sentry

Hi I want to switch to users accounts and browse their profiles I found this tutorial [Easily impersonate any user in laravel 5 app](http://blog.mauriziobonani.com/easily-impersonate-any-user-in-a-laravel-application/) about impersonating but it works for laravel 5 and I am using laravel 4

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the Auth facade within a controller

`Auth::loginUsingId($userId);`

Of course you need to make sure the controller has appropriate restrictions to block unauthorized use of it.